# Automate Group Policy Windows OS settings using Powershell scripting

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-3.0, group-policy, windows-administration

I want to automate some Windows OS settings in Group policy (Run -> gpedit.msc). I want to use PowerShell for automating the below OS settings. Curious to know how do we automate it ?

> • Go to Run-> gpedit.msc •
>
> Administrative Templates --> System ->
> Device Guard -> Turn on Virtualization Based Security --> Enabled
>
> • Select platform Security level -> Secure Boot and DMA Protection
>
> • Virtualization Based Protection of Code Integrity - > Enabled with
> UEFI Clock
> • Credential Guard Configuration --> Enabled with UEFI
> Clock

I found the [LINK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/ee461027(v=technet.10)) to be having some documentation in this regard. But couldn't make out how to use it to achieve the automation of the above settings.
I'm very new to Powershell scripting & in general OS settings. Can anyone help me here ?

Comment: GPO settings are just registry entries.

Comment: Are you working in an Active Directory environment? What are you trying to accomplish? Automating the -creation of GPO objects-, or enabling/disabling specific registry settings? In a typical AD environment, the point of Group Policy is to create a GPO object with a set of defined settings and apply it to a set of computers. The settings are then automatically applied to those computers and enforced.